# invalidateOptionsMenu doesnt get called from fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a fragment with that needs to build its own action bar :

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

public CalendarFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.calendar_menu1, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setText("Calendar Fragment");
    return textView;
}
```

}

the problem is it doesnt create a new menu with items from calendar_menu1 but just adds the items from it to the old menu, as if invalidateOptionsMenu doesnt work (i tried getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu() too)

Comment: what old menu, are you sure you don't have a onCreateOptionsMenu in your activity too?

Comment: What you mean exactly by **new menu**? A menu with no items except those,  you  have just created?

Answer (score 5):

You must call in onCreate():

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is normal, looking into the javadoc of the [MenuInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.Menu%29), "*The items and submenus will be added to this Menu*":

```
public void inflate (int menuRes, Menu menu) 
Inflate a menu hierarchy from the specified XML resource. Throws InflateException if there is an error.

Parameters
menuRes  Resource ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.menu.main_activity) 
menu  The Menu to inflate into. The items and submenus will be added to this Menu.
```

Did you try to call `menu.clear()` before to inflate your fragment menu?

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.calendar_menu1, menu);
}
```